# Ajax Response set back to default language instead of current

Tags: 8, ajax

On AJAX Call. It set to default language instead of current language. On AJAX route calling below function

```
public function ajaxList(Request $request) {
    $response = new AjaxResponse();

    $selector = $request->request->get('selector');
    $path = $request->request->get('base_path');

    $current_path = \Drupal\Core\Path\CurrentPathStack;

    $current_path->setPath('/' . $path, $request);

    $build = $this->processData($request);

    $response->addCommand(new ScrollTopCommand("$selector"));
    $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand("$selector", $build));

    return $response;
  }
```

In processData calling my Custom Form

```
 private function processData() {
    $form_state = (new FormState())
      ->setStorage([
        'rerender' => TRUE,
      ])
      ->setMethod('get')
      ->setAlwaysProcess()
      ->disableRedirect();

    $form_state->set('ajax', TRUE);

    $form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->buildForm('Drupal\my_module\Form\TestForm', $form_state);

    return $form;
  }
```

It will reset My Form's Label back to English.

Comment: How does your site determine current language?

Comment: On basis of  `$language =  \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();`

Comment: I mean what negotiation method(s) are you using?

Comment: Didn't get u about negotiation method.

Comment: How does your site determine the current language? URL/domain prefix? Something else?

Comment: Yes Correct {lang_code}/domain  prefix lang_code =  current language user selected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74741/discussion-between-julia-and-clive).

Comment: Sorry, no time to chat. If you could edit your question and add the extra info that’d be great, it should help someone give you an answer

Comment: It's on will add more info in question. Updated question

Comment: But you still haven't answered the question - how does your site determine language? Is it by domain? A URL prefix? Some other method?

Comment: By URL only. Example: `<abc.com>/ch/page-name`. Here ch is Chinese language

Comment: That's by language prefix. You need to make your AJAX request to the correct language domain (so you will need to prefix the path with /ch/). This will ensure that the response is generated in the correct language.

Comment: Thanks @Jaypan. Yes it works.:) Thanks a lot again